# How to get the value of a single table cell?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a table (sap.ui.table.Table) and have been trying to get the single cell value but can't figure it out.

In my table I used `rowSelectionChange` like so:

```
rowSelectionChange: function (e) {                 
    var idx = e.getParameter('rowIndex');
    if (oTable.isIndexSelected(idx)) {
        var cxt = oTable.getContextByIndex(idx);
        var path = cxt.sPath;
        var obj = oTable.getModel().getProperty(path);
        console.log(obj);
    }
}
```

When I select a single row I get the following output in my console:

```
[object Object] {
   index: 1,
   name: "name"
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to retrieve the value of index. In this case 1. Also, I would like this data to show if there was a click anywhere in the row. I tried this with `cellClick` but I don't get any output in the console.

Here is my [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/carele/edit?js,console,output).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the value of index you can just call:

```
console.log(obj.index);
```

The cellClick event is marked as experimental, but you can try to add the following event handler to the table:

```
cellClick : function(event) {
    console.log(event.getParameter("cellControl").getText());
}
```

Comment: I thought I tried `console.log(obj.index);` but I guess not. Both work. I found a different way using jquery : `$("#myTable").on("tap", "tr", function (e) { var index = $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
                console.log(index);
            });` but when I set the column (Index) to `visible: false` it doesn't work. But anyway this answers my original question so thank you!

Comment: Is there anyway of firing the event `rowSelectionChange` if the user clicks anywhere in the row?

Comment: I found a way to hide the column using the following css style: `td:nth-child(2), th:nth-child(2){
    display: none;
}`

Comment: Be careful with using jQuery directly as it might not work as expected due to the fact that UI5 uses jQuery internally but adds its own logic on top.